# How do you exit a cocossharp application?

Tags: exit, cocossharp

How do you exit a cocossharp application ? And before you answer please note that CCApplication has been replaced with CCGameview in the latest version (V4.0.30319) of cocossharp. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked before.  You are not really supposed to end mobile apps as explained here: [Please see this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808358/how-do-you-exit-an-application-in-cocossharp)